# Simple Button using DRAW GUI in GameMaker

Tags: game-maker

This is my button under DRAW GUI.

```
if point_in_rectangle(window_mouse_get_x(),window_mouse_get_y(),790,317,943,385)
{ var hover=1; } else { var hover=0; }
draw_sprite(spr_mainmenu_smallbutton,hover,865,360);
if (distance_to_point(mouse_x,mouse_y)<=0)
{
if mouse_check_button(mb_left)
draw_sprite(spr_mainmenu_smallbutton,2,865,360); 
}
draw_set_color(make_colour_rgb(163,190,240));
draw_set_font(fnt_mainmenu_text);
draw_text(865,350,"New  Game");
```

Fairly simple. It draws a rectangle and the text "New Game" on it.
When the mouse hovers over it, it lights up. When you click it, the graphic changes. It's a good button.

The problem occurs when I enter the area of the button while HOLDING the mouse button.

[image]

See how it behaves? Instead of lighting up, it gets pressed.

All because I am holding the mouse button as I come in. Any way to avoid this and have it light up instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `mouse_check_button_pressed()` instead `mouse_check_button()`.
Something like this:

`Create` event:

```
button_pressed = false;
mouse_over = false;

button_x = 865;
button_y = 350;
button_width = 153;
button_height = 68;

button_left = button_x - button_width div 2;
button_right = button_left + button_width - 1;
button_top = button_y - button_height div 2;
button_bottom = button_top + button_height - 1;
```

`Step end` event:

```
mouse_over = point_in_rectangle(device_mouse_x_to_gui(0), device_mouse_y_to_gui(0), button_left, button_top, button_right, button_bottom);

if !mouse_over
    button_pressed = false;
else
{
    if mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)
    {
        button_pressed = true;
    }
    else if mouse_check_button_released(mb_left) and button_pressed
    {
        // action
        show_message("pressed");
    }
}
```

`Draw GUI` event:

```
if button_pressed
    draw_sprite(sprite_index, 0, button_x, button_y);
else if mouse_over
    draw_sprite(sprite_index, 1, button_x, button_y);
else
    draw_sprite(sprite_index, 2, button_x, button_y);
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. :)

Comment: Hey I have a question. The code above works perfectly. Only thing I've noticed is that when I release the button, and the action happens, the button has the pressed down graphic. Is it possible for the action to occur only after the sprite changes back to normal after the click?

Comment: Add `button_pressed = false;` before your action. If it won't help, then change it to `button_pressed = false; alarm[0] = 1;` and inside `alarm 1` place your action code.